# Summing every cell in nth column with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a dynamic sheet that contains a variable number of rows and columns. The sheet begins with a standard 4 columns, then additional groups of 8 columns added to the standard 4, depending on when the time is that the report is drawn.

I need to sum the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th column cells across the groups of 8 to arrive at the sums of the 2nds, 3rds, 4ths, and 5ths column cell entries - for each row.

My sense is that I have to add these values to an array using a loop with Step, but this is my first use of an array in VBA and I'm having trouble conceptualizing it!

Any help would be appreciated :)

I am a novice at VBA, but am slowly learning by example - I have not attempted something of this complexity.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is the latest version - from the 365 subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get it with VBA code.

- Using an array(aCol) to keep the columns index is not necessary in your case because it is continous and sequential. It makes the code more flexible for other projects. i.e. you have to get the result for column 1,4,5,8 with the same logic.

[image: Data samples]

```
Sub demo()
    Dim arr, res(), aCol, i, j, k
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Integer
    arr = [a1].CurrentRegion.Value
    iRow = UBound(arr)
    iCol = UBound(arr, 2)
    ReDim res(1 To iRow, 1 To 4)
    aCol = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)
    For j = 0 To UBound(aCol)
        res(1, j + 1) = "SUM-COL" & aCol(j)
    Next
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 0 To UBound(aCol)
            For k = 5 To iCol Step 8
                res(i, j + 1) = res(i, j + 1) + arr(i, k + aCol(j) - 1)
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Cells(1, iCol + 2).Resize(iRow, 4).Value = res
End Sub
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. It works exactly as intended, thank you. Very clean implementation also. I didn't realize I could use a UBound in a For loop! Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not tied to VBA, here's a lambda function to do what you want:

```
SUMBYGROUPINDEX =LAMBDA(row, position_to_sum, group_width,
    LET(
        groups, DROP(row, , 4),
        group_columns, SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(groups)),
        group_indices, MOD(group_columns - 1, group_width) + 1,
        SUMPRODUCT(groups * (group_indices = position_to_sum))
    )
);
```

It's used like this:

[image]

It takes three parameters:

1. row - which is the data from the first of the standard four columns to the last column of the last group of 8
2. position_to_sum - an integer <= 8 indicating which position within the groups of 8 you want to sum in this cell. In the example above, I've put the numbers 2, 3, 4 and 5 in the row above where the formulas are, so I can reference them. As shown, I'm using U$2 to say "Sum the 2nd columns from the groups"
3. group_width - in your example, this is 8 - but if that were to change, you could just put a different number in here

To break down how this works:

Let:

- groups be the data after the first four columns (use the DROP function to remove the first four columns from the row)
- group_columns be the sequence of integers from 1 to COLUMNS(groups), which is some multiple of group_width - of 8 in your case
- group_indices be the integers one through group_width (8) for each of the groups

Then, take the sum product of the data in the groups multiplied by those array elements where the group_indices array matches the position_to_sum.

If you're not sure how to add this lambda function to your workbook, please install [Excel Labs and the Advanced Formula Environment](https://pages.store.office.com/addinsinstallpage.aspx?assetid=WA200003696&rs=en-US&correlationId=f2538bf8-021d-7964-a8cb-d2d228bc0ab8), then paste the code above into the 'Modules' tab:

[image]

After you hit save, you'll be able to use the function as you would any other function in Excel.

Comment: Very interesting - I'd prefer not to install extra features if I don't have to - I appreciate the response!

Comment: You don't have to install the add-in to use lambda functions. You can define it in the Name Manager as well.